# UITableView scrolling with custom cell subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a following problem with `UITableView` scrolling. 
In my setup, there are `2 rows per section`, and each section takes a full frame of the `UITableView`.
If I add a `subview` of some `viewController` to the second `cell's contentView`, like

```
if (![cell.contentView.subviews containsObject:cell.player.view]) {
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.player.view];
}
```

(here, `cell.player` is the `MPMoviePlayer` control which has been initialized),
during the scrolling to the next `section`, first `cell` will be white until scroll completes.

Now, I noticed that this is related to the `addSubview` function, since no matter what view I add, it displays the same behaviour. I can get rid of this by implementing

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     /// detect cell
     [cell.contentView.subviews[0] setHidden:YES];
 }
```

or by removing it from the `superview` in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, but then, it looks very weird if the view suddenly disappears.
It only happens on `cells` which contain a custom `subview` (for `cells` without it, it 
works smoothly).

My question is, does anyone know how to avoid white area during the scrolling, without removing/hiding the view before the scrolling?

For a better visual clue, here's a screenshot with proper behaviour if I don't add `subview`:

[image: snag.gy/uDUV2.jpg]

and a screenshot with view. Note that next image is white

[image: snag.gy/GBQgw.jpg]

Comment: Modifying the cell's content view directly may cause some problems. Try using a custom UITableViewCell subclass which can be setup by the `player`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me as though you have already subclassed `UITableViewCell` and added a property called `player` which is the `MPMoviePlayer`.

My suggestion would be to avoid adding the subview from the `UIViewController` controlling the `tableView`, and to actually get the cell to handle this itself.

The UITableViewCell should manage it's own subviews, and ideally the datasource should not be getting involved.

It's difficult to give you a solid recommendation on how to go about doing this without seeing the code for your custom `UITableViewCell`, however, if you are waiting for the `MPMoviePlayer` to initialise before you add the subview, the cell could very easily be using KVO or some other way of motoring the player control to find out when it initialises, and then act on it.

Comment: Well, I do use subclassed `UITableViewCell` with a `UIViewController` property. I tried to avoid putting any controller code within `UITableViewCell` and let the `UITableView` / custom `UIViewController` manage the content within the cell. Currently, I initialize view controller on cell initialization, and add its subview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` whenever I find out cell doesn't contain the subview.

Comment: The solution was basically to move all of controls initialized in controller to the UITableViewCell, as @infinity-james suggested. Thank you!